# Select the application window and PostMessage

Tags: c#, postmessage, setforegroundwindow

I created the application (KeySimulator) which is running on the Windows VM. This app is sending an 'ENTER' key to another application (DraftSight). DraftSight is running on the same VM. Maine purpose of my app is to select DraftSight and click 'ENTER' just in case if any messages are pop up on the DraftSight.
Everything is working except my app sometimes is not recognizing the DS app.
My app is running 24/7 and I have a Task to start my app on a log-in or if my app is not running.
This is my code for that function:

[DllImport("USER32.DLL", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
public static extern IntPtr FindWindow(string lpClassName, string lpWindowName);

[DllImport("USER32.DLL")]
public static extern bool SetForegroundWindow(IntPtr hWnd);

IntPtr draftSightHandle = FindWindow("Qt5QWindowIcon", null);

SetForegroundWindow(draftSightHandle);

const UInt32 WM_KEYDOWN = 0x0100;
PostMessage(draftSightHandle, WM_KEYDOWN, (int)Keys.Enter, 0);

Comment: At a quick glance, your only criteria for identifing th target window is the class name "Qt5QWindowIcon", which may not be unique enough. Any QT-based program will use the very same class name, and in case of having more than one window with the same class, Windows will pick up one of them at random, if you happen to have two QT programs opened at once. Try setting the title too.

Comment: How can I pass class and title into PostMessage? Or do I have to use a different method for it?

Comment: No, into the `FindWindow` call, where you identify the target window. Its second parameter is the window title so you can narrow down your search. `PostMessage` and all other API calls just use that handle.

Comment: Understood. Let me try it.

Comment: The first string is a class the second one is the title.
This is how I defined it:
draftSightHandle = FindWindow("Qt5QWindowIcon", "DraftSight");
It's not recognizing the DraftSight at all.